# jQuery tokeninput plugin, problem when returning results with 1 char digit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

Does anyone use jquery tokeninput plugin for tag autocmpletition?

I have a problem, when i digit the first char in input search starts and results are ok, but dropdown autocompletition doesn't shows me results and shows me no results text, in firebug console i see :

`error: invalid quantifier on plugin line 661.`

if i digit more then 1 char everything is ok

what should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the plugin. The plugin in the source does a RegExp on the propertyToSearch.
If the property has characters which are keywords in the RegExp then because the RegExp fails, the addition also fails. 
I tried working around with 'onResult' callback but wasn't successful. So, I changed my data and removed any '+', '/', '?' etc which might conflict with regexp.

Hope it helps.